# Remove more than two returns and more than one space within php string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, spaces, carriage-return

I manage to remove the spaces but I can't understand why it would remove my returns as well. I have a textarea in my form and I want to allow up to two returns maximum. Here is what I have been using so far.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string); // supposed to remove more than one consecutive space - but also deletes my returns ...
$string = preg_replace('/\n\n\n+/', '\n\n', $string); // using this one by itself does not do as expected and removes all returns ...
```

It seems first line already gets rid of more than one spaces AND all returns ... Which is strange. Not sure than I am doing it right ...

Comment: use \h instead for horizontal whitespaces

Comment: Thanks. How about my return carriages? ... It still removes all returns using second preg_replace

Comment: you must enclose your replacement string between double quotes.

Comment: no double quotes don't matter. FYI, the php string is coming from a textarea field in a form. I just can't find how to replace two or more returns by two returns ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who will need it, that's how you remove two carriage returns from a textarea.

```
preg_replace('/\n\r(\n\r)+/', "\n\r", $str);
```

For the space issue, as it has been posted above, replace \s by \h

Comment: You mean "that's how you remove two or more carriage returns from a textarea." right? (Thanks, BTW. That's exactly what I needed!)

Answer (score 1):

Because `\s` will also match newline characters. So i suggest you to use `\h` for matching any kind of horizontal spaces.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\h\h+/', ' ', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
```

See the deifinition of `\s`.It includes `\n`.Use

```
\h  matches any horizontal whitespace character (equal to [[:blank:]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\h` for horizontal whitespaces.